# Анимированый линейный переход по клику

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, css-animation

Добрый день уважаемые. Подскажите, пожалуйста как реализовать анимацию перехода линейного градиента при background у дива, по клику на кнопку Пример

```js
$("button").on("click", function(){
 $(".block").animate({background: "linear-gradient(to bottom, #4b5fff 60%, #ebebeb)"}, 1000);
})
```

```css
.block{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0D343A 40%, #000); 
}
button{
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="block"></div>
<button></button>
```

Необходимо реализовать что б по клику на button из одного линейного градиента все перестроилось в другой за 1сек. Это вообще реально?

Answer (score 2):

По клику добавляй кнопке класс , а этому классу напиши анимацию на css "@keyframes" c нужными точками и переходами

Comment: как быть если вместо дива у меня тег body? Перефразирую вопрос - Как по нажатию на кнопку менять тегу body линейный градиент ?

Comment: тоже самое что и с дивом , давать боди класс ,  котором описываешь анимацию , которая допустим сработает через 1-2 секунды и плавно меняет градиент , при добавлении класса анимация начнет работать

Comment: (http://css.yoksel.ru/animation-for-gradients/) пример градиент анимации